# Apache ECharts how to display Total (sum) value for pie chart in Title Subtext?

Tags: echarts

[piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar0Lg.png)

i had created a pie chart over Apache Echarts, may i know is there a way to show the total value in the title subtext?

```
option = {
title: [{
    text: 'Sales',
    subtext: 'Total Sales: ' , //wish to show total value over here
    left: '50%',
    textAlign: 'center'
}],
dataset: {
        source: [
            ['OUTLET A', 100],
            ['OUTLET B', 52],
            ['OUTLET C', 200],
            ['OUTLET D', 334],
            ['OUTLET E', 430],
            ['OUTLET F', 330],
            ['OUTLET G', 220]
        ]
    },
series: [
    {
        name: 'Sales',
        type: 'pie',
        label: {
            show: true,
            textBorderWidth: 2,
            position: 'outside',
            color: "#a4311d",
            formatter: '{c} ({d}%)'
        }
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign your dataset to a local variable and create sum function for it.

```
let data = [['OUTLET A', 100],
            ['OUTLET B', 52],
            ['OUTLET C', 200],
            ['OUTLET D', 334],
            ['OUTLET E', 430],
            ['OUTLET F', 330],
            ['OUTLET G', 220]]
```

In you dataset:

```
dataset: {
        source: data},
```

Create a sum function to calculate the sum:

```
const sum = data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return prev + current[1]
}, 0);
```

Display the sum in the title subtext:

```
subtext: 'Total Sales: '+sum
```